# Solve this system using elimination for $x(t)$, $y(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Here are my system of equations:

$$x'+y'-x=5$$

$$x'+y'+y=1$$

I rearranged them like so:

$$x=x'+y'-5$$

$$y=1-x'-y'$$

I took the derivative of

$$x=x'+y'-5$$

and got

$$x'=x''+y''\Rightarrow y''=x'-x''$$

This is where everything just went south for me...

Since I don't have a $y''$ anywhere I took the second derivative of the easiest equation involving $y$ that I could find:

$$y'=1-x'-y'$$

$$y''=-x''-y''$$

Which means:

$$y''=-x''-(x'-x'')\Rightarrow y''=-x''-x'+x''\Rightarrow y''=-x'$$

But from here I'm just completely confused and don't know where and what I should be substituting anymore.  I've tried googling "elimination for differential equation" and I get nothing.  It's an online class and there is no documentation on how to use elimination for system of equations with multiple variables and derivatives.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Moo giving me $y=-4-x$?

Comment: OK, I've done that and got constants for $x$ and $y$, but I'm under the impression that I should have functions as solutions?

Comment: I'm supposed to be solving for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ @Moo

Comment: @Moo, Ok, I just don't see nor understand how that is correct given the context of the question

Comment: What if $x(t) = -5, y(t) = 1$. Do they satisfy both equations?

Comment: @Moo I see what you mean now... thanks again

Comment: why does it repeat $x' + y' \; ?$

Comment: @WillJagy nope, I double checked.  There is no typo

Comment: in that case, second minus first gives $y+x = -4,$ so that $x' + y' = 0,$ finally $x=-5$ and $y=1$

Comment: @WillJagy OK, that's what I got, I just didn't believe it.  Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has
$$5+x=x'+y'=1-y\ ,$$
which implies $x+y=-4$, hence $x'+y'=0$. This then leads to the single constant solution $x=-5$, $y=1$.